# Laravel + Flatpicker: How to Install using NPM

Tags: laravel, flatpickr

Did is what I did so far

1. `npm i flatpickr --save`
2. Add `@import "~flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.css";` to the app.scss
3. index.blade.php

```php
@section('content')
<div class="form-group">
<label for="loaned">Loaned</label>
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="loaned" id="loaned">
</div>
@endsection

@section('scripts')
    <script>
        flatpickr('#loaned')
    </script>
@endsection
```

I get an error, "flatpickr is not defined". I read the documentation but it, I don't know what to do with this part:

```php
// commonjs
const flatpickr = require("flatpickr");

// es modules are recommended, if available, especially for typescript
import flatpickr from "flatpickr";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add do this in one of two ways:

In your `app.js` (usually under the resources folder):

```
import flatpckr from 'flatpickr';
window.flatpckr = flatpckr;
```

This will expose the `flatpckr` function in your global `window` object.

An alternative is to add all your script code in your script files instead of in the blade files e.g.:

```
import flatpckr from 'flatpickr';

// Maybe add conditions on when to run this
flatpckr('#loaned');
```

This way you don't "pollute" your window object with a bunch of libraries without needing to.

Comment: Nice one, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this case I add the following line to `webpack.mix.js`

```
mix.copy('node_modules/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.css', 'public/css/flatpickr.css');
```

and import the css file the regular way.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/flatpickr.css" />
```

Addition: of course you need to run `npm run dev` and if you use versioning, add the file to your git.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

1. `npm i flatpickr --save`
2. Register `flatpickr` in the `resources/js/app.js`

```js
require('./bootstrap');
require('alpinejs');
require("flatpickr");
```

3. Add an import `flatpickr` in the `resources/css/app.css`

```css
@import 'flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.css';
```

4. Run the `npm run dev` or `npm run watch`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can try this package.
https://github.com/Laratipsofficial/laravel-flatpickr

This package is created for easier integration between Laravel and flatpickr.

Quoted from their readme: "Using this package you can add a beautiful date or datetime picker into your project without touching any javascript with the power or laravel component. It is just a laravel component wrapper for the Flatpickr javascript library."

Answer (score 0):

Using a cdn and importing in a Laravel blade file i found works for me.
I just imported like this:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>
    <script>
    flatpickr("#reserved_from", {});
    

    </script>
```